# Make function run after page loads and edit Label's innerHTML without ID or a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to design my teachable-based website, and I can only edit the following relevant fields:

> HTML/JavaScript code snippets inside the **head** tag on all pages.
>
> custom CSS across all pages on your site.

I have jQuery.

While this is pretty limiting I manage to get by. However, I ran into a problem:
I am trying to edit the text of this object:

[a picture of the object I am trying to edit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFx7K.png)

Basically, I am trying to edit the inner HTML of both

```
<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<label for="student_message">Message</label>
```

From "Subject" to "נושא" and from "Message" to "הודעה".

These labels have no classes and ID's, and their only attributes are "for" attributes.
Now, if it helps, these specific labels are inside these divs:

```
<form id="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <label for="student_message">Message</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

These are the only lables on the site inside the "contact-form" div.

So, the problems are:

- I need to access these labels from the HEAD tag, and they are in the
  BODY tag. So I guess I need some sort of a waiting function to run
  after the page/form loads.
- I can only differenciate these labels from
  others using their attribute and their parent div's attributes.

My questions:

1. How do I make a function that runs after the page loads but doesn't make the whoe page freeze?
2. Inside that function, How do I access objects using their attributes?
3. And just because it seems important and I don't know it yet, how do I access objects within objects?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Select by tag and attribute, for html `$('label[for="subject"]').html(yourhtml)`, for text `$('label[for="subject"]').text(yourtext)`

Answer (score 0):

You said you had jQuery available, so enclosing your code in `$(document).ready(` ensures the body is loaded.  Then use jQuery selector to find object by attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("label[for='subject']").html('נושא');
  $("label[for='student_message']").html('הודעה');
});
```

Comment: Well, appearantly I already knew the solution but the problem wasn't with my code but rather with the fact that the "HTML/JavaScript code snippets inside the head tag on all pages." doesn't really function on all pages. You sending me this code snippet shows me that the problem isn't with our code but with the platform. I will contact teachable's support to tell them that. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The elements of interest can be found *relative to* element(s) that can be found directly - ie elements identified by id/class.

For example ...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    const $formGroup = $('#contact-form div.form-group').eq(0);
    $formGroup.find('label').eq(0).text('נושא');
    $formGroup.find('label').eq(1).text('הודעה');
});
```

Alternatively, if you prefer not to make an assignment ...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#contact-form div.form-group').eq(0)
    .find('label').eq(0).text('נושא')
    .next('label').text('הודעה');
});
```